# List all subdirectories on given level

Tags: python

I have backup directory structure like this (all directories are not empty):

```
/home/backups/mysql/
    2012/
        12/
           15/
    2013/
        04/
           29/
           30/
        05/
           02/
           03/
           04/
           05/
```

I want to get a list of all directories containing the backups, by providing only a root directory path:

```
get_all_backup_paths('/home/backups/mysql', level=3)
```

This should return:

```
/home/backups/mysql/2012/12/15
/home/backups/mysql/2013/04/29
/home/backups/mysql/2013/04/30
/home/backups/mysql/2013/05/02
/home/backups/mysql/2013/05/03
/home/backups/mysql/2013/05/04
/home/backups/mysql/2013/05/05
```

And those ***should not*** be present in the result:

```
/home/backups/mysql/2012
/home/backups/mysql/2012/12
/home/backups/mysql/2013
/home/backups/mysql/2013/04
/home/backups/mysql/2013/05
```

Is there any way to `os.listdir` 3 levels down, excluding all the other levels? If yes, I would appriciate your help.

```
def get_all_backup_paths(dir, level):
    # ????
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
from glob import iglob

level3 = iglob('/home/backups/mysql/*/*/*')
```

(This will skip "hidden" directories with names starting with `.`)

If there may be non-directories at level 3, skip them using:

```
from itertools import ifilter
import os.path

l3_dirs = ifilter(os.path.isdir, level3)
```

In Python 3, use `filter` instead of `ifilter`.

Comment: Then you need: `level3_dirs = [x for x in level3 if os.path.isdir(x)]`

Comment: Currently, `filter` is a built in function in python 3.8, so importing from itertools won't work and isn't necessary.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `glob` to search down a directory tree, like this:

```
import os, glob
def get_all_backup_paths(dir, level):
   pattern = dir + level * '/*'
   return [d for d in glob.glob(pattern) if os.path.isdir(d)]
```

I included a check for directories as well, in case there might be files mixed in with the directories.

Answer (score 0):

import functools, os

```
def deepdirs(directory, depth = 0):
    if depth == 0:
        return list(filter(os.path.isdir, [os.path.join(directory, d) for d in os.listdir(directory)]))
    else:
        return functools.reduce(list.__add__, [deepdirs(d) for d in deepdirs(directory, depth-1)], [])
```