# Applying function to a list of file-paths and writing csv output to the respective paths

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, os.path

How do I apply a function to a list of file paths I have built, and write an output csv in the same path?

> read file in a subfolder -> perform a function -> write file in the
>   subfolder -> go to next subfolder

```
#opened xml by filename
with open(r'XML_opsReport 100001.xml', encoding = "utf8") as fd:
    Odict_parsedFromFilePath = xmltodict.parse(fd.read()) 

#func called in func below
def activity_to_df_one_day (list_activity_this_day): 
    ib_list = [pd.DataFrame(list_activity_this_day[i], columns=list_activity_this_day[i].keys()).drop("@uom") for i in range(len(list_activity_this_day))]
    return pd.concat(ib_list)

#Processes parsed xml and writes csv 
def activity_to_df_all_days (Odict_parsedFromFilePath, subdir): #writes csv from parsed xml after some processing
    nodes_reports = Odict_parsedFromFilePath['opsReports']['opsReport']
    list_activity = []
    for i in range(len(nodes_reports)):
        try:
            df = activity_to_df_one_day(nodes_reports[i]['activity'])
            list_activity.append(df)

        except KeyError:
            continue
    opsReport = pd.concat(list_activity)
    opsReport['dTimStart'] = pd.to_datetime(opsReport['dTimStart'], infer_datetime_format =True)
    opsReport.sort_values('dTimStart', axis=0, ascending=True, inplace=True, kind='quicksort', na_position='last')
    opsReport.to_csv("subdir\opsReport.csv") #write to the subdir




def scanfolder(): #fetches list of file-paths with desired starting name.

    list_files = []

    for path, dirs, files in os.walk(r'C:\..\xml_objects'): #directory containing several subfolders
        for f in files:
            if f.startswith('XML_opsReport'):
                list_files.append(os.path.join(path, f))
    return list_files

filepaths = scanfolder() #list of file-paths
```

Every function works well, the xml processing is good, so I am not sharing the xml structure. There are 100+ paths in `filepaths` , each a different subdirectory. I want to be able to apply above flow in future as well, where I can get filepaths and perform desired actions. It's important to write the csv file to it's sub directory.

Comment: It's not totally clear to me what you're requesting; Is this helpful? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35315873/python-3-travel-directory-tree-with-limited-recursion-depth

Comment: I was able to solve

Comment: You can post your own solution and accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was able to solve with  `os.path.join`.

```
    exceptions_path_list =[]
    for i in filepaths:
        try:
            with open(i, encoding = "utf8") as fd:
                doc = xmltodict.parse(fd.read())
                activity_to_df_all_days (doc, i)
        except ValueError:
            exceptions_path_list.append(os.path.dirname(i))
            continue

    def activity_to_df_all_days (Odict_parsedFromFilePath, filepath):
        ...
        ...
        ...    
        opsReport.to_csv(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(filepath), "opsReport.csv"))
```

Answer (score 1):

To get the directory that a file is in, you can use:

```
import os

for root, dirs, files, in os.walk(some_dir):
    for f in files:
        print(root)
        output_file = os.path.join(root, "output_file.csv")
        print(output_file)
```

Is that what you're looking for?

Output:

```
somedir
somedir\output_file.csv
```

See also [Python 3 - travel directory tree with limited recursion depth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35315873/python-3-travel-directory-tree-with-limited-recursion-depth) and [Find current directory and file's directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5137497/find-current-directory-and-files-directory).