# Retrieve files from only the third level of directory

Tags: python, directory, subdirectory, python-os

I have a directory which has the following form :

A/ : the root

B/: The first level subdirectory which contains the following directories

```
01/  02/ 03/ 04/ 05/ 06/ 07/
```

C/:  third leve where each subdirectory from B/  (01/ or 02/ or 03/ or 04/ or 05/  or 06/ or 07/)
contains up to three  subdirectories

001/ 002/ 003/

It's at 001/ 002/ 003/ that l want to retrieve files :

My tree is as follow : 
A/B/C/01/001/files.txt

How can l access that ?

**What l have tried ?**

```
    for root, dirs,files in sorted(os.walk(path+ "/", topdown=False)):  # root

        for lab in dirs:  # level 1 
            new_path=path+category+'/'+lab+'/'
            for ro,dir,f in os.walk(new_path): #level 2
                for dr in dir:
                    for ri, dir, file in os.walk(new_path+'/'+dr): #level 3 
                        os.chdir(new_path+'/'+dr)
                        text_file=glob.glob("*.txt")
```

Is there any efficient way to do that avoiding 5 nested for loops ?

Comment: Are you wanting to retrieve files from inside  001/ 002/ 003 directories in the output?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python 3 - travel directory tree with limited recursion depth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35315873/python-3-travel-directory-tree-with-limited-recursion-depth)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This alone when I try works for me

```
import os

path = r'C:\root'

for root, dirs,files in os.walk(path):  # root
    for f in files:
        print(f)
```

This outputs all files on level 3. Which is essentially files contained in the  three subdirectories 001/ 002/ 003/ from each of the 7 directories on level B.