# How to recurse exactly two directories deep in python, only need directory names?

Tags: python, operating-system, markdown

I am trying to automate the directory map for a Johnny Decimal directory as an R Markdown document. My Python script only returns the top level directory. I do not get the second level down at all.

I have tried using "import pathlib" and "import os". I got further with "import os"

```
import os

path = "c:\\local\\top"

print("# Johnny Decimal\r\n")

for d1 in filter(os.path.isdir, os.listdir(path)):
    path2 = path + "\\" + d1
    print("## " + d1 + "\r\n")
    for d2 in filter(os.path.isdir, os.listdir(path2)):
        print("### " + d2 + "\r\n")
```

I get:

```
# Johnny Decimal

## 10

## 20
```

I expected to get:

```
# Johnny Decimal

## 10

### 11

### 12

## 20

### 21

### 22
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35315873/python-3-travel-directory-tree-with-limited-recursion-depth - you'd need to modify it to give directory names, but that gives you what you need to set depth level with os.walk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`os.listdir` returns just the file names without path names, and yet `os.path.isdir` expects the full path names, so you should use `os.path.join` to join the path names with the file names before you pass it to `os.path.isdir`:

```
for d1 in os.listdir(path):
    path2 = os.path.join(path, d)
    if os.path.isdir(path2):
        print("## " + d1 + "\r\n")
        for d2 in os.listdir(path2):
            if os.path.isdir(os.path.join(path2, d2)):
                print("### " + d2 + "\r\n")
```