# How can I break this loop once the file I want in os.walk() is found?

Tags: python, recursion, os.walk

I am using an os.walk() loop and if statement to find the path of a file. It works, however after the path is found and printed the loop doesn't break for a few seconds after this. I want to break the loop after the path I want is printed. New to recursion so this is where I am falling short.

Code:

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk('C:\\'):
  for file in files:
     if file == 'vipkidt.exe':
          path = str(os.path.join(root, file))
          print(path)

Output>> C:\Program Files (x86)\VIPKIDT\vipkidt.exe
         # 3-4 seconds passes..
         Process finished with exit code 0
```

Wanted path is printed fairly qucikly, 3-4 seconds passes, then loop breaks. I want these 3-4 seconds shaved off. I have tried adding a `break` at each the inner and outer for loop, however didn't do the trick. I referenced these posts here but still wasn't clicking: [ref1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35315873/travel-directory-tree-with-limited-recursion-depth), [ref2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/229186/os-walk-without-digging-into-directories-below)

Comment: 'break' keyword

Comment: [break](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#break)

Comment: Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing documentation and tutorials.  Loop control is included in any tutorial on the topic.  We expect you to do that research before posting here.  Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: I know I need a `break` keyword, I already tried that before posting the question, the missing piece was the empty `dirs` as @Justin mentioned below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `break` to get out of the `for file in files` loop and empty `dirs` to get out of the `os.walk` loop

```py
for root, dirs, files in os.walk('C:\\'):
    for file in files:
        if file == 'vipkidt.exe':
            path = str(os.path.join(root, file))
            print(path)
            dirs[:] = []
            break
```

Comment: The empty `dirs` is what I was missing, Thanks!