# Get specific layer of subfolders' name in Python

Tags: python, split, operating-system, os.walk

For a folder named `test` with subdirectories structure as follows in Windows environment:

```
├─a
│  ├─a1
│  ├─a2
│  └─a3
│      ├─a3_1
│      ├─a3_2
│      └─a3_3
├─b
│  ├─b1
│  ├─b2
│  ├─b3
│  └─b4
└─c
    ├─c1
    ├─c2
    └─c3
```

I want to get the name of subfolders of the second layer and save them in `list`: `a1, a2, a3, b1, b2, b3, b4, c1, c2, c3...`

```
base_dir = r"..\test"

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(base_dir):
    print(root)
```

Output:

```
..\test
..\test\a
..\test\a\a1
..\test\a\a2
..\test\a\a3
..\test\a\a3\a3_1
..\test\a\a3\a3_2
..\test\a\a3\a3_3
..\test\b
..\test\b\b1
..\test\b\b2
..\test\b\b3
..\test\b\b4
..\test\c
..\test\c\c1
..\test\c\c2
..\test\c\c3
```

**UPDATE:** I try to use the `split` method by backslashes and save to `mylist`:

```
base_dir = r"..\test"
mylist = []

**Method 1:**
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(base_dir):
    li = root.split('\\')
    #Only if the list has 3 elements of more, get the 3rd element
    if len(li) > 3:
        #print(li[3])
        mylist.append(li[3])
        #print(mylist)
mylist = list(set(mylist))
mylist.sort()
print(mylist)

**Method 2:**        
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(base_dir):
    try:
        li = root.split('\\')
        mylist.append(li[3])
    except IndexError:
        pass
mylist = list(set(mylist))
mylist.sort()
print(mylist)
```

Output:

```
['a1', 'a2', 'a3', 'b1', 'b2', 'b3', 'b4', 'c1', 'c2', 'c3']
```

It's OK right now, thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [List all subdirectories on given level in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16810686/list-all-subdirectories-on-given-level-in-python)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your output, it's clear that `root.split('\\')` doesn't always have 3 elements in it, hence `print(root.split('\\')[2])` throws index out of range, I would suggest checking the length of the list first, and then getting the 3rd element

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(base_dir):
    li = root.split('\\')
    #Only if the list has 3 elements of more, get the 3rd element
    if len(li) > 2:
        print(li[2])
```

The output will be

```
a
a
a
a
a
a
b
b
b
b
c
c
c
```

Then to make your `mylist` as per updated question you can append all the elements to mylist first, then use [itertools.groupby](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) to remove consecutive duplicates at one go instead of creating a list out of set at every step

```
from itertools import groupby

mylist = []
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(base_dir):
    li = root.split('\\')
    #Only if the list has 3 elements of more, get the 3rd element
    if len(li) > 3:
        val = li[3].strip()
        #If element is non-empty append to list
        if val:
          mylist.append(val)

#Remove consecutive repeated elements by using groupby
result = [x[0] for x in groupby(mylist)]
print(result)
```

The output will be

```
['a1', 'a2', 'a3', 'b1', 'b2', 'b3', 'b4', 'c1', 'c2', 'c3']
```

Answer (score 3):

You get an index error when there isn't a sub-directory at `[2]` (For example, something like `C:\\SomeEmptyFolder`)

This should work fine

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(base_dir):
    try:
        print(root.split('\\')[2])
    except IndexError:
        pass
```